# Using pulled Docker image - Postgres error (Spring Boot, Postgres)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I pushed simple Spring Boot web app with Postgres on Docker Hub.
[image]

But when i pulled it and try to run it in Docker Desktop i got: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed

[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
COPY target/docker-compose-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar test.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/test.jar"]
```

Docker compose:

```
services:
psql-db:
image: postgres
container_name: persons-db
restart: always
environment:
  - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345
  - POSTGRES_DB=persons
  - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
ports:
  - '5432:5432'

api:
 container_name: persons-api
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
 ports:
  - '8080:8080'
 environment:
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://psql-db:5432/persons
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=12345
  - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=create
 depends_on:
  - psql-db
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Only api image has to be on Docker Hub. It can be run via docer-compose.yaml file. Download it from Github and run in console: docker-compose up -d